# Set Image Size for certain images

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner here so please ELI5.

I am trying to upload photos and have a set size for when they display. The photos will more than likely be larger than the settings - which makes me think this is possible. I have tried CSS and the width works, but the height does not. I have given the images their own class and have only been using CSS. This is what I have tried:

```
.img-list{
 max-height: 175px;
 max-width: 263px;

}
```

I have also tried

```
.img-list{
max-height: 100%
max-width: 100%
}
```

I feel like I could put something in the .php files of the theme, but I am not sure where.

With my CSS, the image will resize, but only to the width and the height will not stretch. I understand that the images will stretch and not look like the originals, but the images are going to be small in size and little detail so the stretch would not be significant (I believe). I know this has to be possible. I have been scouting the internet and see others talking about it. A lot of the other threads mention HTML. I don't know where I would put the HTML. When I put the HTML in the image itself it doesn't change anything. The CSS still takes over and does not properly work. This is the HTML I have tried.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="URL"><span class="img-list"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-801" src="URL" alt="image name" width="512" height="512" /></span></a></p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="URL/"><span class="img-list"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-801" src="URL" alt="img name" width="100%" height="100%" /></span></a></p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="URL"><span class="img-list"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-801" src="URL" alt="image name" width="300" height="200" /></span></a></p>
```

All HTML codes result in the same image - CSS is active. This leads me to believe I need to put some HTML in my .php files... but where and what would it be?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried putting the class on the image?

Comment: Your html declaration of height overrides the css settings

Comment: I have tried putting the class on the image. That's how it readjust, but only for the width.  --- Steven, when I put the height and width at 263x175 or even 300x200 the images stay the exact same. If the HTML overides, why does it stay the same for both images?